# Highland Park Einar: estimated age

Tags: whiskey

I received a bottle of [Highland Park Einar](http://highlandpark.co.uk/shop/einar/). It's one of the 6 bottles released of the [Warrior series](http://whiskyforeveryone.blogspot.de/2013/02/new-release-highland-park-warriors.html). Given there is no age statement, would anyone of you who tried it be able to tell what's the approximate age of this scotch? Does it even matter in this case?

Also: [I have read](http://www.bestshotwhiskyreviews.com/2013/06/highland-park-einar-review.html) it has been developed by the marketing department, not by the distiller. Does that mean in general anything in regards of the quality of the whisky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Age Statement (NAS) Scotch Whiskies give you only one item of information you can rely on - they are at least 3 years old (otherwise they can not be called Whisky)

The 40% gives you no useful information - in the Warrior range you have:

- Svein - 40% - 40Euro
- Einar - 40% - 53Euro
- Harald - 40% - 75Euro
- Sigurd - 43% - 150Euro
- Ragnavald - 44.6% - 400Euro
- Thorfinn - 45.1% - 1000Euro

(Taken from [somersetwhisky.com](http://www.somersetwhisky.com/review-highland-parks-warrior-series/))

Those first 3 are all 40% alcohol but are very different blends from different casks.

There higher end of this range is likely to be older, and higher quality, and the Thorfinn has a specified 60% first fill cask (hence its colour and rich flavour) but they will each have whisky from casks of a variety of ages from 3 years and upwards, chosen in order to give the end product the required characteristics.

As with all whiskies - try the ones you can and go with the ones you like :-)

Answer (score 2):

From what I can gather on the whiskey it is bottled at 40% which is low  for a scotch

so taking this into consideration I would have a guess at this whiskey being around the 10-12 year old mark but nobody can really be certain as all 6 of the Warrior series did not have an age on the bottle